# How to edit a Google Presentation

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been tying to access to the content of a Google presentation by opening by ID but i haven't had succes on it so i was wondering if anybody knows how to do it, Please i´ll be very gratefull, this was my example.

```
    var NombreDeUsuario = "MY_NAME";

//This ID is from a google presentation.
    var docid = DocsList.getFileById("1uF7xY9_QjSqFsILcq5IxGaJuzK6GlPLO-O4dWVG80cI").makeCopy().getId();

//here is where it says that it doesn´t found it
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid).setName(NombreDeUsuario);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var rate = "Excelent";
    var body = doc.getActiveSection();


      body.replaceText("%DATE%", date);
      body.replaceText("%RATE%", rate);
      doc.saveAndClose();
```

Answer (score 1):

DocumentApp is only for opening Google Documents. I don't think there is a way to edit Presentations using GAS. [There is an open issue on the topic](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573).